# FB needs to reload couple times after login

Tags: facebook, cakephp, authentication

I am using Cakephp Facebook Plugin and so far it all works except for the fact that I need to reload my page once or twice before the user is acutally logged in...

I checked the refresh part of the fb login and it works, just doesn't give me the data I need...

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',function(){
                    window.location.reload()
 });
```

Comment: Is this after the FB.login() is called? And what data are you trying to retrieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',function(){
                    window.location.reload()
 });
```

Before blindly reloading the page, you should check the response being returned.

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login',function(response){
       var isLoggedIn = decodeResponse(response);
       if(isLoggedIn )
                    window.location.reload()
       else
                    showErrorMessage(response);
 });
```